# Open ultimate version project solution in premium version

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to open and work with the Project file in Premium Edition of Visual studio 2010 which was developed in Ultimate Edition?

Does Microsfot Visual Studio 2010 supports cross edition compatibility?

Comment: Following links will guide you on this [Visual Studio 2010 Comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison) [VS & TFS 2010 Beta 2 has arrived](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/10/19/VS-TFS-2010-Beta-2-has-arrived.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal C# or VB.Net projects will open just fine, but projects like architecture modelling which is only supported in Ultimate will fail to load in Premium. But these projects generally take no part in the build so you will still be able to build the solution in premium.